# Partial changing of some Placeholders in Html through CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, colors, placeholder

So I am having a few input fields, where some are rquired to be filled, others not.
And I would like to add an *red* * at the end of each Placeholder where that is the case to indicate which one have to be filled, while all the other Placeholders, and the parts before the *, keep there normal color/or one of my choosing?

Note: Already tried Labels, and stuff, as well as putting the *´s just behind the input fields-which did work, but unfortunately looked Horrible.

Here is the code

Html

```
<input type="text" id="ISBN_VALUE" name="ISBN_VALUE" placeholder="ISBN"> 

<input type="text" id="TITLE_VALUE" name="TITLE_VALUE" placeholder="Titel">

<input type="text" id="AUTHOR_VALUE" name="AUTHOR_VALUE" placeholder="Autor">

<input type="text" id="COPY_VALUE" name="COPY_VALUE" placeholder="Anzahl">

<input type="text" id="PRICE_VALUE" name="PRICE_VALUE" placeholder="Preis">

<input type="text" id="COMMENT_VALUE" name="COMMENT_VALUE" placeholder="Kommentar">

<input type="text" id="USER_VALUE" name="USER_VALUE" placeholder="Benutzer">
```

And here the current CSS

```
    ::placeholder {
```

color:    #ff0000;
}

Comment: unfortunately you can't style parts of the canonic placeholder independently. Plus the input element is self contained and can't be easily used to add an absolute positioned element on top (especially with the ::after pseudo selector). As per best practice and accessibility criteria the placeholder is just supposed to show an example of the input. The asterisk should be marked outside because it would be lost when you typed text inside. Of course you are free to implement any logic you prefer, but I think it will require using contenteditable divs and custom styling

Comment: That is unfortunate.... Putting it outside messes up the Layout quiete a lot.... Guess I have to live with it...

Comment: please take it only as a suggestion among many but there are solutions that might surprise you. Did you every try flex or grid layout strategies? in case you didn't and you don't want to get overwhelmed with the possibilities you might be inspired by the bootstrap css framework just to begin with. Put an eye here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ where it shows various form examples having labels and input pairs arranged in a 12 cols layout pattern. I cited one of many of course. Or just look at css flex box layout.